# Offline tokens not allowed for the user or client in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Offline tokens not allowed for the user or client in Keycloak 23.x is seen all of a sudden.

I have a bunch of users who are able to fetch the access_token for a while and this error starts happening all of a sudden

```
{
    "message": "400 Bad Request: \"{\"error\":\"not_allowed\",\"error_description\":\"Offline tokens not allowed for the user or client\"}\"",
    "status": 400,
    "timestamp": "2023-12-01T16:20:16.788228"
}
```